# WPF Text file in solution, not Debug directory

Tags: wpf, file

I created txt file and added it to my solution in "Text" directory. I tried to read it using:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text\t.txt");
```

but it says that there's not any file "Text\t.txt" in Debug directory. I want to have all files in solution. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on that file in the solution explorer and select Properties. Then make sure that `Build Action` is set to `None` and that `Copy to output directory` is set to `Copy Always`

Also make sure that you escape the `\` character:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Text\\t.txt");
```

[image]

Comment: "Text\t.txt" was just an example. I know about '\'. Thanks for help. Works